# Add vertical lines at POSIXct intercepts using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I am making a time series plot of bike availability at stations. So far, I am able to plot the availability by 10-minute intervals.  Note that `created_at.x` is in POSIXct format.

```
> head(Pershing, n =20)
       id status available_bike_count available_dock_count        created_at.x station_summary_id citibike_station_id latitude longitude
41473 293 Active                    2                   57 2015-10-01 05:20:08              82792                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41474 293 Active                    3                   56 2015-10-01 09:20:10              82816                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41475 293 Active                    4                   52 2015-10-01 12:00:06              82832                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41476 293 Active                    3                   56 2015-10-01 04:50:06              82789                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41477 293 Active                    3                   56 2015-10-01 06:30:08              82799                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41478 293 Active                    2                   57 2015-10-01 05:10:07              82791                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41479 293 Active                    9                   47 2015-10-01 12:40:06              82836                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41480 293 Active                    2                   57 2015-10-01 07:10:06              82803                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41481 293 Active                    1                   57 2015-10-01 00:00:12              82760                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41482 293 Active                    3                   56 2015-10-01 05:00:07              82790                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41483 293 Active                    1                   56 2015-10-01 02:50:07              82777                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41484 293 Active                    3                   56 2015-10-01 08:40:06              82812                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41485 293 Active                   49                    7 2015-10-01 22:50:07              82897                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41486 293 Active                   11                   44 2015-10-01 16:40:07              82860                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41487 293 Active                    3                   54 2015-10-01 01:40:06              82770                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41488 293 Active                    5                   52 2015-10-01 11:10:07              82827                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41489 293 Active                    9                   47 2015-10-01 18:40:13              82872                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41490 293 Active                    8                   48 2015-10-01 12:20:08              82834                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41491 293 Active                    2                   56 2015-10-01 00:40:06              82764                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
41492 293 Active                    4                   52 2015-10-01 12:50:06              82837                 519 40.75188  -73.9777
```

```
ggplot(data=Pershing,aes(x= created_at.x, y=available_bike_count)) + 
  geom_point(colour="red") + 
  ylab("Available Bikes") + 
  xlab("time")
```

[image]

I would like to add vertical lines (actually bars), that show time frames. The time frame should begin at `Pershing_trucks$stoptime` and end at `Pershing_trucks$starttime`

```
> Pershing_trucks
        X bikeid end.station.id start.station.id diff.time
10   2785  19911            359              519       930
12   3052  23301            359              519      1406
14   3496  23818            359              519      1164
15   3778  23185            359              519      1515
17   3795  21630            359              519      1563
21   5046  22144            359              519       884
22   5063  19132            359              519      1396
24   5461  22994            359              519      1574
25   5861  22176            359              519      1394
27   5956  14716            359              519      1932
32   6341  18099            359              519      1267
33   6415  19432            359              519      1143
34   6763  17121            359              519       827
35   6800  22616            359              519      1693
38   7694  20754            359              519      1690
39   8224  15323            359              519      2465
40   8626  23472            359              519      1046
43   8903  19348            359              519      1724
45   8952  24236            359              519      1289
49   9664  24246            359              519      2723
50   9729  18330            359              519      2030
51   9730  18330            359              519      2438
55  10460  22067            359              519      1069
56  10461  22067            359              519      1635
59  11906  22430            359              519       617
62  12310  17727            359              519      1749
64  12557  15174            359              519      1280
65  12568  24123            359              519      2843
72  13572  20687            359              519      1541
77  15530  22913            359              519      1052
80  15863  16252            359              519       893
82  16901  24265            359              519      3316
85  17731  23792            359              519       751
87  19130  17144            359              519      2162
89  21064  15553            359              519      1817
91  21572  22077            359              519       719
92  21789  19456            359              519      3313
95  22822  19639            359              519      1837
98  24345  20860            359              519      1682
102 25520  17632            359              519      1553
112 28679  20514            359              519      3297
120 30827  19110            359              519      3118
121 31258  16744            359              519      3081
               stoptime           starttime             midtime
10  2015-10-01 08:30:16 2015-10-01 08:45:46 2015-10-01 08:38:01
12  2015-10-01 08:20:30 2015-10-01 08:43:56 2015-10-01 08:32:13
14  2015-10-01 06:23:14 2015-10-01 06:42:38 2015-10-01 06:32:56
15  2015-10-01 07:04:10 2015-10-01 07:29:25 2015-10-01 07:16:47
17  2015-10-01 07:40:59 2015-10-01 08:07:02 2015-10-01 07:54:00
21  2015-10-01 06:51:46 2015-10-01 07:06:30 2015-10-01 06:59:08
22  2015-10-01 07:43:37 2015-10-01 08:06:53 2015-10-01 07:55:15
24  2015-10-01 06:20:39 2015-10-01 06:46:53 2015-10-01 06:33:46
25  2015-10-01 06:46:05 2015-10-01 07:09:19 2015-10-01 06:57:42
27  2015-10-01 08:12:16 2015-10-01 08:44:28 2015-10-01 08:28:22
32  2015-10-01 06:23:19 2015-10-01 06:44:26 2015-10-01 06:33:52
33  2015-10-01 06:25:58 2015-10-01 06:45:01 2015-10-01 06:35:29
34  2015-10-01 06:33:12 2015-10-01 06:46:59 2015-10-01 06:40:05
35  2015-10-01 07:23:30 2015-10-01 07:51:43 2015-10-01 07:37:36
38  2015-10-01 06:41:24 2015-10-01 07:09:34 2015-10-01 06:55:29
39  2015-10-01 06:52:20 2015-10-01 07:33:25 2015-10-01 07:12:52
40  2015-10-01 06:47:52 2015-10-01 07:05:18 2015-10-01 06:56:35
43  2015-10-01 07:37:51 2015-10-01 08:06:35 2015-10-01 07:52:13
45  2015-10-01 06:48:08 2015-10-01 07:09:37 2015-10-01 06:58:52
49  2015-10-01 07:01:33 2015-10-01 07:46:56 2015-10-01 07:24:14
50  2015-10-01 07:00:07 2015-10-01 07:33:57 2015-10-01 07:17:02
51  2015-10-01 07:55:18 2015-10-01 08:35:56 2015-10-01 08:15:37
55  2015-10-01 07:30:05 2015-10-01 07:47:54 2015-10-01 07:38:59
56  2015-10-01 08:16:32 2015-10-01 08:43:47 2015-10-01 08:30:09
59  2015-10-01 07:17:48 2015-10-01 07:28:05 2015-10-01 07:22:56
62  2015-10-01 07:25:07 2015-10-01 07:54:16 2015-10-01 07:39:41
64  2015-10-01 07:25:30 2015-10-01 07:46:50 2015-10-01 07:36:10
65  2015-10-01 09:34:44 2015-10-01 10:22:07 2015-10-01 09:58:25
72  2015-10-01 08:40:39 2015-10-01 09:06:20 2015-10-01 08:53:29
77  2015-10-01 07:47:57 2015-10-01 08:05:29 2015-10-01 07:56:43
80  2015-10-01 08:49:59 2015-10-01 09:04:52 2015-10-01 08:57:25
82  2015-10-01 08:59:52 2015-10-01 09:55:08 2015-10-01 09:27:30
85  2015-10-01 07:51:10 2015-10-01 08:03:41 2015-10-01 07:57:25
87  2015-10-01 08:06:23 2015-10-01 08:42:25 2015-10-01 08:24:24
89  2015-10-01 08:15:09 2015-10-01 08:45:26 2015-10-01 08:30:17
91  2015-10-01 08:50:32 2015-10-01 09:02:31 2015-10-01 08:56:31
92  2015-10-01 08:53:47 2015-10-01 09:49:00 2015-10-01 09:21:23
95  2015-10-01 08:20:05 2015-10-01 08:50:42 2015-10-01 08:35:23
98  2015-10-01 08:34:41 2015-10-01 09:02:43 2015-10-01 08:48:42
102 2015-10-01 08:37:07 2015-10-01 09:03:00 2015-10-01 08:50:03
112 2015-10-01 08:51:15 2015-10-01 09:46:12 2015-10-01 09:18:43
120 2015-10-01 08:56:43 2015-10-01 09:48:41 2015-10-01 09:22:42
121 2015-10-01 09:43:33 2015-10-01 10:34:54 2015-10-01 10:09:13
```

```
> dput(Pershing_trucks)
structure(list(X = c(2785L, 3052L, 3496L, 3778L, 3795L, 5046L, 
5063L, 5461L, 5861L, 5956L, 6341L, 6415L, 6763L, 6800L, 7694L, 
8224L, 8626L, 8903L, 8952L, 9664L, 9729L, 9730L, 10460L, 10461L, 
11906L, 12310L, 12557L, 12568L, 13572L, 15530L, 15863L, 16901L, 
17731L, 19130L, 21064L, 21572L, 21789L, 22822L, 24345L, 25520L, 
28679L, 30827L, 31258L), bikeid = c(19911L, 23301L, 23818L, 23185L, 
21630L, 22144L, 19132L, 22994L, 22176L, 14716L, 18099L, 19432L, 
17121L, 22616L, 20754L, 15323L, 23472L, 19348L, 24236L, 24246L, 
18330L, 18330L, 22067L, 22067L, 22430L, 17727L, 15174L, 24123L, 
20687L, 22913L, 16252L, 24265L, 23792L, 17144L, 15553L, 22077L, 
19456L, 19639L, 20860L, 17632L, 20514L, 19110L, 16744L), end.station.id = c(359L, 
359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 
359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 
359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 
359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L, 359L), start.station.id = c(519L, 
519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 
519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 
519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 
519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L), diff.time = c(930L, 
1406L, 1164L, 1515L, 1563L, 884L, 1396L, 1574L, 1394L, 1932L, 
1267L, 1143L, 827L, 1693L, 1690L, 2465L, 1046L, 1724L, 1289L, 
2723L, 2030L, 2438L, 1069L, 1635L, 617L, 1749L, 1280L, 2843L, 
1541L, 1052L, 893L, 3316L, 751L, 2162L, 1817L, 719L, 3313L, 1837L, 
1682L, 1553L, 3297L, 3118L, 3081L), stoptime = structure(c(1443706216, 
1443705630, 1443698594, 1443701050, 1443703259, 1443700306, 1443703417, 
1443698439, 1443699965, 1443705136, 1443698599, 1443698758, 1443699192, 
1443702210, 1443699684, 1443700340, 1443700072, 1443703071, 1443700088, 
1443700893, 1443700807, 1443704118, 1443702605, 1443705392, 1443701868, 
1443702307, 1443702330, 1443710084, 1443706839, 1443703677, 1443707399, 
1443707992, 1443703870, 1443704783, 1443705309, 1443707432, 1443707627, 
1443705605, 1443706481, 1443706627, 1443707475, 1443707803, 1443710613
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "EST"), starttime = structure(c(1443707146, 
1443707036, 1443699758, 1443702565, 1443704822, 1443701190, 1443704813, 
1443700013, 1443701359, 1443707068, 1443699866, 1443699901, 1443700019, 
1443703903, 1443701374, 1443702805, 1443701118, 1443704795, 1443701377, 
1443703616, 1443702837, 1443706556, 1443703674, 1443707027, 1443702485, 
1443704056, 1443703610, 1443712927, 1443708380, 1443704729, 1443708292, 
1443711308, 1443704621, 1443706945, 1443707126, 1443708151, 1443710940, 
1443707442, 1443708163, 1443708180, 1443710772, 1443710921, 1443713694
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "EST"), midtime = structure(c(1443706681, 
1443706333, 1443699176, 1443701807.5, 1443704040.5, 1443700748, 
1443704115, 1443699226, 1443700662, 1443706102, 1443699232.5, 
1443699329.5, 1443699605.5, 1443703056.5, 1443700529, 1443701572.5, 
1443700595, 1443703933, 1443700732.5, 1443702254.5, 1443701822, 
1443705337, 1443703139.5, 1443706209.5, 1443702176.5, 1443703181.5, 
1443702970, 1443711505.5, 1443707609.5, 1443704203, 1443707845.5, 
1443709650, 1443704245.5, 1443705864, 1443706217.5, 1443707791.5, 
1443709283.5, 1443706523.5, 1443707322, 1443707403.5, 1443709123.5, 
1443709362, 1443712153.5), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("X", 
"bikeid", "end.station.id", "start.station.id", "diff.time", 
"stoptime", "starttime", "midtime"), row.names = c(10L, 12L, 
14L, 15L, 17L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 43L, 45L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 55L, 56L, 59L, 62L, 64L, 65L, 
72L, 77L, 80L, 82L, 85L, 87L, 89L, 91L, 92L, 95L, 98L, 102L, 
112L, 120L, 121L), class = "data.frame")
```

Ideally, the plot would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Where is the data with `starttime` and `stoptime`? Or how are the calculated? You reference the columns but they are not in the data you share. Also please share with `dput()` so it is copy/pasteable and we don't have to manually convert to POSIX and other classes. `dput(droplevels(head(my_data, 20)))` is nice.

Comment: It's on multiple lines. Scroll down in the `Pershing_truck` data set window (the second one). But I completely agree with the need to use `dput`, which is why I only provided an approximate solution

Comment: Ah, I see now. But it makes less sense now - does OP want a rectangle for *every row* in `Pershing_trucks`? The picture show 6 rectangles, not anything like 50.

Comment: I would like a rectangle for every row, yes - the last image is just so you have an idea of what the rectangles would look like, also I have added `dput`

Comment: Next time when you ask a question, please try to make it **minimal**. Here you share 8 columns of data in Pershing_trucks but only use two and 9 columns of Pershing data and only use two. It makes your question less clear and much longer than necessary to show all the irrelevant bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking is fairly straightforward, we just need to add a `geom_rect` layer with your `Pershing_trucks` data.

I didn't want to bother importing your `Pershing` data frame, so after getting the `Pershing_trucks` data from your `dput()` I sampled/simulated a `Pershing` data frame like this:

```
Pershing = data.frame(
    created.at.x = sample(Pershing_trucks$starttime, 20),
    available_bike_count = rpois(20, 20)
)
```

Let's create a basic plot we can add the rectangles to in different ways:

```
persh_plot =
    ggplot(
        data = Pershing,
        aes(x = created.at.x, y = available_bike_count)
    ) +
    geom_point(color = "red") +
    ylab("Available Bikes") +
    xlab("time") + theme_bw()
```

I like the `geom_rect` of the other answer, but the `lapply` is unnecessary. Also, aesthetic constants (like `ymin = -Inf`) should always be set *outside* of `aes()`. We'll also need to set `inherit.aes = FALSE` to prevent the earlier `x` and `y` mappings from being inherited:

```
persh_plot +
    geom_rect(
        data = Pershing_trucks,
        aes(xmin = stoptime,
            xmax = starttime),
        ymin = -Inf,
        ymax = Inf,
        fill = 'gray80',
        alpha = 0.2,
        inherit.aes = FALSE
    )
```

[image: plot1]

I'm not sure what you're trying to show - but here the alpha transparency on the rectangles gives a fairly nice indication of overlap. Remember that my `Pershing` data has similar structure to yours, but is simulated. You may want to add the `geom_point()` layer after the rectangle layer so the points are on top.

This doesn't match your desired output very well, so here's a version with outline rectangles without any fill, and with the y min and max at 0 and 20 as in your plot. Looks terrible to me, but to each their own:

```
persh_plot +
    geom_rect(
        data = Pershing_trucks,
        aes(xmin = stoptime,
            xmax = starttime),
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 20,
        color = "black",
        fill = NA,
        size = 1,
        inherit.aes = FALSE
    ) +
    expand_limits(y = 0) # just to force y down to 0 with my simulated data
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly complicated problem I think. However, I can give you parts of it and an idea to solve it.

The idea would be to create a loop function to create something like this. It probably doesn't work as is, but with a couple tweaks, it might be able to.

```
vertBars <- lapply(seq_along(Pershing_trucks), function(x) {

             # Start with a vector that is empty
                 vertBars <- 0 

             # Add a ggplot call that creates a grey box with the desired 
             # start and stop times for a single line number "x"  
                 a <- geom_rect(data=Pershing_trucks, aes(xmin=stoptime[x],
                            xmax=starttime[x], ymin=-Inf, ymax=+Inf), fill='gray80',
                            alpha=0.02)                

             # Add the plot "a" to the empty vector you created. This will loop and
             # add all of the bars that you require without having to manually specify them
                vertBars <- vertBars + a

             # Return the vector "vertBars" that should be able to be added to your plot
                return(vertBars)

             }
```

Also, it might be a smart idea to add `+ theme_bw()` for a plot like this because it looks far cleaner.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're looping/applying. `geom_rect` is vectorized (I can't think of a `geom` that isn't). It should work fine if you get rid of the `lapply` and the `[x]`s to just add a single `geom_rect` call to the plot if this is what's desired.

Comment: The reason I'm using a loop is because originally I reasoned that plotting every single row using the same color would be a poor idea as a result of the overlap. With this loop, he can create a `b` that will do even rows and `a` will do odd rows, resulting in alternating colors for better visualization. However, I removed the `b` and just didn't remove the loop.

Comment: `seq_along(dataframe)` is equivalent to `1:ncol(dataframe)`, so I still think your `lapply` is confused as it seems to mix rows and columns up. Initializing `vertBars` as a numeric vector and then trying to add `ggplot` layers to it will result in an error as well. And what you're trying to accomplish with the `lapply` is built in to `geom_rect`... you don't need the `lapply` or the `[x]`. A single `geom_rect` layer like you have, if you delete the `[x]`s, can be added directly to the original plot.

Comment: If you want to alternate colors you can add `color =  rep_len(c("red", "blue"), length.out = nrow(Pershing_trucks))`. No loops needed, no applies needed.